# How do remove data from a certain weekday period from a R time-series?

Tags: r, time-series, xts

I have a R xts timeseries. How can I create a new timeseries from it, which contains all the data from the original, except the data points occurring on Monday between 12:00 and 18:00?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one way to do it.

```
x <- .xts(rnorm(100), as.POSIXct("2011-01-06 10:00:00")-100:1*3600)
x[with(as.POSIXlt(index(x)), !(wday==1 & hour > 12 & hour < 18)),]
```

And if you only need the times between 12:00-18:00 you can use xts-subsetting like this:

```
x["T12:00/T18:00"]
```

Comment: Wow, subsetting is really cool! I just looked at it's documentation, but I can't see any reference for the "T12:00" syntax (the T part). Any other magic letters? BTW, I noticed that you are one of the XTS authors. Congrats for making such a nice package!

Comment: @Adal I mentioned it because it's not easy to find.  It's mentioned in `?.parseISO8601`.